# How to read a NodeList inside another NodeList

Tags: java, xml

How can I read another `NodeList` from a main `NodeList`. See below.(If possible, can I assign the second `NodeList` as an array i.e if main `NodeList` is at element 2 the inner `NodeList` displays element 2's "element2")

```
NodeList MKIAPIIndividual = document.getElementsByTagName("MKIAPIIndividual");
for (int temp1 = 0; temp1 < MKIAPIIndividual.getLength(); temp1++) {                
    Node nNode1 = MKIAPIIndividual.item(temp1);                                

    if (nNode1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {    
                    
       Element eElement1 = (Element) nNode1;

       //1 . foedselsdato
       String foedselsdato = eElement1.getElementsByTagName("foedselsdato").item(0).getTextContent();  
       foedselsdato_value[temp1] = foedselsdato;

       //2. medisinering
       NodeList medisinering= document.getElementsByTagName("element2");
       for (int temp = 0; temp < medisinering.getLength(); temp++) {                
          Node nNode = medisinering.item(temp);
          //System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
                        

           if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
           Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

           String element29 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("merknad").item(0).getTextContent();                    
           medisinering_merknad_value[temp] = element29; 
           String element30 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("preparat").item(0).getTextContent();                    
           medisinering_preparat_value[temp] = element30;
           String element31 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("tilbakeholdelsesdato").item(0).getTextContent();                    
           medisinering_tilbakeholdelsesdato_value[temp] = element31;  

                        } 
                    } 

                }
            }
```

I want to read through an xml. For field "foedselsdato" it works fine .My XML is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
     <Root>
             <MKIAPIIndividual>
                     <foedselsdato>2012-04-29</foedselsdato>
                     <medisinering>
                        <element2>
                                <merknad/>
                                <preparat>11 Mastipen vet Intramammarie 300 mg/sprøyte</preparat>
                                <tilbakeholdelsesdato>2020-08-25</tilbakeholdelsesdato>
                        </element2>
                        <element2>
                                <merknad/>
                                <preparat>11 Penovet vet Inj væske, susp 300 mg/ml</preparat>
                                <tilbakeholdelsesdato>2020-08-25</tilbakeholdelsesdato>
                        </element2>
                    </medisinering>
                     
             </MKIAPIIndividual>
             <MKIAPIIndividual>
                     <foedselsdato>2015-07-15</foedselsdato>
                     <medisinering>
                        <element2>
                                <merknad/>
                                <preparat>22 Mastipen vet Intramammarie 300 mg/sprøyte</preparat>
                                <tilbakeholdelsesdato>2020-08-20</tilbakeholdelsesdato>
                        </element2>
                        <element2>
                                <merknad/>
                                <preparat>22 Penovet vet Inj væske, susp 300 mg/ml</preparat>
                                <tilbakeholdelsesdato>2020-08-25</tilbakeholdelsesdato>
                        </element2>
                     </medisinering>
              </MKIAPIIndividual>             
     </Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change made andit worked.

```
NodeList medisinering= eElement1.getElementsByTagName("element2");
```